# Nativescript RadAutoCompleteTextView disable filtering suggestion

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-angular

Is there any way to disable filtering suggestion? Cause I really want to display all the data returned from my REST API. Regardless what the user type.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution.

First defined custom TokenModel class

```js
class CustomTokenModel extends TokenModel {
  constructor(text, displayText, image) {
    super(text, image);
    this.displayText = displayText;
  }
}
```

Then we should add SuggestionView with displayText prop

```xml
<RadAutoCompleteTextView
ref="autocompleteView"
  >
    <SuggestionView ~suggestionView suggestionViewHeight="51">
      <StackLayout v-suggestionItemTemplate orientation="vertical">
        <v-template>
          <StackLayout>
            <Label :text="item.displayText"></Label>
          </StackLayout>
        </v-template>
      </StackLayout>
    </SuggestionView>
  </RadAutoCompleteTextView>
```

and last, loadAsyncSuggestions function

```js
async getSuggestions(text) {
      let suggestionsData = await this.getSuggestions(text);
      let suggestions = suggestionsData.map(item => new CustomTokenModel(text, item.someProp))
      return suggestions;
}
```

Now, it will display all returned items, because it filters text by itself.
But in suggestion view you can display any data that you want.

You can look it on this page:

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-ui-feedback/issues/702